# Missing dependencies when installing the Tedious Node.js package

Tags: node.js, express, npm, tedious

I am trying to create an API using Node.js, Express, Tedious, and MSSQL Server. When I run the command 'npm install tedious' everything seems to run fine and install. But if I run try and run the program using 'node server.js' I get an  error saying that I am missing some dependencies. If I use the command 'npm list' I can see the missing dependencies, here is some of the output from 'npm list':

```
npm ERR! extraneous: ms@2.1.1 C:\node\demo\node_modules\send\node_modules\ms
npm ERR! missing: @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth@2.0.2, required by tedious@9.1.0
npm ERR! missing: @js-joda/core@2.0.0, required by tedious@9.1.0
npm ERR! missing: @azure/ms-rest-azure-env@1.1.2, required by @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth@2.0.2
npm ERR! missing: @azure/ms-rest-js@1.8.15, required by @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth@2.0.2
npm ERR! missing: @types/tunnel@0.0.0, required by @azure/ms-rest-js@1.8.15
npm ERR! missing: @types/node@14.6.0, required by @types/tunnel@0.0.0
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@3.1.0 C:\node\demo\node_modules\follow-redirects\node_modules\debug
npm ERR! missing: @types/node@8.10.62, required by adal-node@0.1.28
npm ERR! extraneous: @types/node@8.10.62 C:\node\demo\node_modules\adal-node\node_modules\@types\node    
npm ERR! extraneous: form-data@2.3.3 C:\node\demo\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data
npm ERR! extraneous: qs@6.5.2 C:\node\demo\node_modules\request\node_modules\qs
npm ERR! extraneous: safe-buffer@5.2.1 C:\node\demo\node_modules\string_decoder\node_modules\safe-buffer 
npm ERR! extraneous: depd@2.0.0 C:\node\demo\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\depd
npm ERR! extraneous: iconv-lite@0.5.2 C:\node\demo\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\iconv-lite
```

All I have done in the environment is install express and tedious using npm, the SQL server was already installed on my machine when I started. I have never ran into this problem with npm before, usually the install command is enough to get it to work properly. I have tried using the node package 'npm-install-missing' but that didn't seem to work. Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share the log when you run `node server.js` too.

Comment: @akolliy I am away from my work machine for the weekend so I can't get this information now. I remember that the output of 'node server.js' was complaining about missing modules, specifically those Azure modules required by tedious that you can see are missing in the output I have from 'npm list' above. If you need the exact output then you will have to wait until monday for me to get my hands on my machine again.